# Vertical alignment of cells in LyX

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, lyx

How can you set the vertical alignment of table cells in LyX? The right-click menu shows three choices ("Top", "Middle", "Bottom") but none of them is enabled, they are all greyed out.

Comment: You need to load the array package (no idea how that translates to lyx, sorry)

Comment: This corresponds to `p`, `m` or `b` type columns, respectively, which means you have to assign a width to the columns. Once you do so you should be able to set the vertical alignment as well. (LyX should load `array` itself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vertical alignment of cells in LyX is TeXnically based on the `p`, `m`, or `b` column types offered by the array package. However, for these types you also have to specify a width.

In LyX, just open the "Table Settings" window. After you have specified a width, the "Vertical alignment in row" combo box becomes enabled.

[image]

Comment: This is having no effect for me. The dialog shows a width and Top or Middle for vertical alignment, but the contents still show up at the bottom..  odd.