# Lyx, how can I vertically center entries in a specific cell in lyx (all the tutorials here in the forum didn't help me)

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I saw for instance this post, this didn´t help me :(
[Vertical alignment of cells in LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95320/vertical-alignment-of-cells-in-lyx)

I have this:
[image]

And now I only want to vertically center the marked entries, but I didn´t found any solution, since 3 days :(.

Comment: Hi and welcome, could you provide some code you have tried so far so people know where you are starting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-read the answer that you linked, because is correct:

[image: mwe]

Verify that you really set `Midlle` in `Vertical alignment in row`  in every column with a **fixed width**, and then that you see only `m` columns in the Code Preview Pane.

Note that an image is  like a huge uppercase letter, so it leave the same bottom space that under "foo" (roughly 3.5pt by default) but not at top, and therefore is it wii be not perfectly centered vertically. A dirty fix  without deal with LateX code directly is just add a similar space above. The generated code should be similar to this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{3cm}|>{\centering}m{3cm}|>{\centering}m{3cm}|}
\hline 
foo & bar & \vspace{3.5pt}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{yourimage}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

The result:

[image: MWE]

Comment: Sorry, you was right!